# onAuthStateChanged isn't executed after reloading the page

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js

This is my firebaseApp.ts file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";   

const config = {
  ...
};

let fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const database = fb.firestore();
database.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  Vue.prototype.$isLoggedIn = firebase.auth().currentUser;
});

export const db = database;
```

I would like to reach isLoggedIn from the App.vue, but when I reload the page and the user is logged in, onAuthStateChanged isn't executed. I have to click on something to get the 'true' value. Where should I initialize isLoggedIn to work properly after refresh too?

Comment: is your other code in this file working ?

Comment: This is all my code in this file. I am probably doing something wrong. If I have this in my firebaseApp.ts file, where should I call it and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for myself! I had to place onAuthStateChanged in my main.ts like this:

```
let app: Vue;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (!app) {
    Vue.prototype.$isLoggedIn = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

I am new to Vue so thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do  `app.firestore();` you should also do `app.auth()....` as follows:

```
let app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const database = app.firestore();
database.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  Vue.prototype.$isLoggedIn = firebase.auth().currentUser;
});
```

Not sure that `app` is the best name for the const to which you pass `firebase.initializeApp(config);`, you may simply call `firebase` or `fb`.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it, but onAuthStateChanged is still not executed when I reload the page... :/

Comment: Do you import Firebase? In the other comment you say that it is all your code but you should import it.

Comment: Of course, I import it. I may have some problem with my toolbar. I would like to refresh the buttons there... I inserted the code.